# Intuitive reason on how predictable processes are defined

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In discrete-time, we say that a process X defined in $\left(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \lbrace\mathscr{F}_n\rbrace, \mathbb{P}\right)$ given by X $ = \lbrace X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$ is predictable if $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, X_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable. An intuitive meaning of this is that, one can predict the value of $X$ at time $n$ despite only having the information at time $n-1$.

However, as defined by Revuz and Yor, for continuous time, a process $X$ is predictable if the map $\left(\omega, t\right) \to X_t(\omega)$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by the space of adapted processes which are left continuous on $\left(0,\infty\right)$.

Can someone enlighten me on the similarity of the two definitions? And how would the "predictability" of $X$ be intuitive from the definition in continuous time (similar to the intuitive meaning in discrete-time)?

Comment: If for each $t\in(0,\infty)$ we have $X_{t}(\cdot)$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable where $\mathcal{F}_{t}:=\sigma(X_{t})$ then $X_{t}(\omega)$ is "adapted" to the family $\mathscr{F}:=\{\mathcal{F}_{t}:t\in(0,\infty)\}$ of sub-sigma-fields of $\mathcal{F}$. The flow of information as $t$ increases is represented by the property $\mathcal{F}_{s}\subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ for all $0<s<t<\infty$. Then $E[X_{t}||\mathcal{F}_{t}]=X_{t}$ and so conditional on information at $t$ we have that $X_{t}$ is known and hence "predictable".

Comment: I think $\mathscr{F}$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the space of adaptable processes to which you refer. The continuity requirement (I think) is needed to allow this "information flow" or "progressive measurability" that adaptability uses to hold.

Comment: Hi. I think what you presented is the intuitive meaning for a process being adapted. Please refer to the first paragraph of the question for what it means to be predictable in the discrete-time case.